# why doesn't a C++ function with template arguments warn "control reaches the end of a non-void function" on clang++ 7?

Tags: c++, function, generics, warnings, clang++

I noticed that if I compile this

```
int x() { }
```

I get a warning, as usual:

```sh
$ clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
main.cpp:5:11: warning: control reaches end of non-void
      function [-Wreturn-type]
int x() { }
          ^
1 warning generated.

$ ./main
```

however, if the function takes any template arguments:

```
template <typename y>
int x() { }
```

no warnings appear.

```sh
$ clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
$ ./main
```

Is this a bug in the compiler?

Comment: Try adding the line `x<int>();` to your main function.

Comment: You don't have a function, only a function template.

Comment: @JaMiT: `x<int>();` does the trick, but it's still strange

Comment: g++ 9.2.1 outputs the expected warning.  Strictly speaking it's UB so no diagnostic is required.

Comment: The compiler is not obligated to warn you. It usually will if it can, but you can in no way rely on it. It is 100% on *you*, the programmer, to write correct code. The compiler may or may not help you do that, but it's under no obligation whatsoever to do so.

Comment: You've just discovered a deep secret of C++, that only ancient C++ gurus know: template functions do not really exist. They are ghosts, ancient spirits. They are a figment of your imagination, an illusion foisted upon you using deep, dark, C++ magick and that template functions only materialize into existence once they are actually used somewhere in the code that provides the actual template parameters, at which point your deepest, darkest fears come into place, and you are find yourself staring into the face of a new, materialized function, with all of its errors and bugs. Be very afraid.

Comment: Templates are in-language macros that obey namespaces and have atrocious syntax and don't pollute, unlike brain-dead text replacement C Preprocessor macro and macro functions which respect nothing.

Comment: @Eljay Macros are token replacement, not text replacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you call (or otherwise odr-use) that function template specialisation, instantiating it, the actual resulting *function* does not exist, and you won't get any diagnostics about it unless it is syntactically invalid.

We cannot see the rest of your program as you did not think a reproducible example was important, but presumably you did not do this in your program.

Write `x<int>();` in your main function and you'll see the warning you wanted.